# How to make sure link opens only in firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

either using javascript, how can i ensure that the link is opened only if browser is firefox, else display an alert? i have code to check for IE but I want to ensure browser is firefox and only than allow to load link, else stay on the page where the link is.

people will normally be accessing the page with IE, but I want some links to be opened in firefox only.

pl advice.

**================EDIT===============**

finally i am settling down for this code:

```
function allow_if_ff(){
    var is_ff = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;  //true or false
    if (!is_ff){
        //window.open ("https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-17.0.2esr&os=win&lang=en-US");
        alert('Please open in firefox');
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    }
}
```

the reason window.open is commented out is because the window is opening, but closing immediately. it is not urgent to have it. so i have commented it.

thx all.

Comment: This is not possible with JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Paul it is very much possible, unless you actually know for fact please don't put other members of searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var is_ff = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;`  this will work for detecting ff

Comment: thx. this works. but then how to force people to people to stay on the page where the link is (i.e. not open th elink, unless browser is firefox). what logic in javascript can be used there?

Comment: i don't know if it was me i would just deactivate/ activate the link with javascript.   you can disable all links in a page with css, a {
    pointer-events:none;
}      just create that with javascript,      also you can set the href in the anchor like so..   <a href="javascript: void(0)">I will not link anywhere</a>  if you can be a little clearer on the purpose or supply more of your code i could probably help out further

Comment: thx. The problem is the page on which this link is going to appear is not owned by me. I only own the page which this link opens. so i am now thinking that i will hardcode the URL of page on which the link is going to be, and then figure how to open that same page when browser is not firefox.

Comment: it doesnt matter if you own the page you can still control the output it generates